# MySQL Provider for VS11 Developer Preview

Tags: .net, mysql, database, visual-studio, ado.net

Is there any MySQL connection provider that integrates with Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview?

I've tried the MySQL connector v6.4.4 but I don't see the option to connect to a MySQL database from the new connection dialog...

Comment: Added vote to close as too localized in time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For as far as I know each mysql connector msi file needs builtin support for a specific version of visual studio. I did a quick search within my Visual Studio 2010 folders and found that there is a Mysql .Net Connector folder in the Extensions folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Oracle\MySQL Connector Net\

I haven't tried it, but you could give it a go copy/paste this folder to your Visual Studio 11 folder. But i'am expecting that there is more to be done than just simple copy/paste it.

Comment: Tried and didn't work. Further searches also turned up nothing. Switching back to VS2010 for the task. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

I tweaked the .Net Connector version 6.5.4 to make it work with Visual Studio 11 developer preview as well as Visual studio 2012.

It a simple matter of adding a few lines to the manifest file.

[It can be downloaded here](http://www.geckon.com/MySQL.Connector.Net.6.5.4.VS2012.vsix)

Just double click it and check the Visual Studio 2012 RC check box.

**Update**
MySQL has released the beta of their connector 6.6.2, with Visual Studio 2012 support. [Get it here.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been trying to build a vsix for this myself for a week now with no luck.

Comment: @jercra no problem, it's a zip-file renamed to vsix, I just added a VS12 section to the manifest file.

Comment: I have tried vs2012.vsx file but not luck. I cannot see the mysql entry in Data Providers list.

Comment: @MohammedVaseemSiddiqui did the install succeed? or did it give you an error message? What version of VS2012 are you running?

Comment: This worked for me. I couldn't run it straight out of Chrome, but had to run it from my desktop, and open it with the Visual Studio Version selector.

Comment: Just installed 6.6.3 beta, works great once you create a Data Connection. Button shows up.

Answer (score 2):

I used Arkain's solution and it worked nicely, untill i wanted to generate the MySQL script to generate my database. In the DDL Generation Template i did not have the  SSDLToMySQL.tt(VS) choice.

This can be solved by copying the 2 files located in `C:\VSPath\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen` some of you might have placed vs somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the "Devart MySQL connector" to solve the problem of connectivity to visual studio 11 and visual studio 2012 RC pack.
I used this connector and it work properly like "MySQL connector/net 6.5.4" work in visual studio 2010.
you can download it from:

1. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/dcmysqlfree.exe
2. http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/download.html

I use this package
"dotConnect for MySQL 7.1 Express"