# MySQL Data Provider not visible in VS 11 Beta

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

I've downloaded the VS 11 Professional Beta, then, after the installation the latest version of the MySQL Connector (Connector/Net 6.5.4) I don't see if it is supported in that VS's version (I want to create the ADO.NET Entity Data Model using the MySQL database). The MySQL Data Provider is not visible in the Data Source field. Under the VS 2010 it works.

### edit

maybe I have to wait [MySQL Provider for VS11 Developer Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616564/mysql-provider-for-vs11-developer-preview)

Comment: I don't know if I saw but I posted a solution on the SO post you have linked.